# How to use Playwright to simulate the click event on a canvas element?

Tags: java, canvas, playwright, autotest

When click everywhere on the canvas, the Playwright Inspector generates the same code:

```
page.click(":nth-match(canvas, 4)");
```

It can't trigger a event that happened on a button or a table line. Anybody could give me a solution to work out a automated test script on canvas?

Comment: "It can't trigger a event that happened on a button or a table line" -- what does this mean? Canvases don't have buttons or table lines, just pixels. I assume the default click will occur right in the middle of the canvas. If you want to add an offset, please provide a relevant sample canvas and explain what the logic is for where the buttons/"table lines" might appear, assuming they're on the canvas, where you need to click, and attempted Puppeteer code as a [mcve] so we have something to work from. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide X Y coordinates with the options object of the click action.

```js
await page.locator('canvas').click({
  button: 'right',
  modifiers: ['Shift'],
  position: { x: 23, y: 32 },
});
```

https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-click

Comment: Thank you very much. I think it can work. I have tried, but meet a error. There are four canvas in this page. I guess the selector is confusing. How can I change the parameter to locate the only one canvas which I want?

Comment: `com.microsoft.playwright.PlaywrightException: Error {
  message='Error: strict mode violation: "canvas" resolved to 4 elements:
    1) <canvas width="2560" tabindex="1" height="1225" data-id=…></canvas> aka playwright.$("canvas")
    2) <canvas width="2560" height="1225" class="webswing-canva…></canvas> aka playwright.$(":nth-match(canvas, 2)")
    3) <canvas width="2566" height="1205" tabindex="-1" data-id…></canvas> aka playwright.$("#wrapper-1750286943 canvas")
    4) <canvas width="2566" tabindex="0" height="1205" data-id=…></canvas> aka playwright.$(":nth-match(canvas, 4)")`

Comment: You can make your selector more specific (I'd need to see the HTML you were targeting to help you with that) or you can simply use `page.locator.nth(4)` to get a single element from the multiple your selector returned.